# API not returning the correct information

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am looking at this API: https://www.distance24.org/api.xhtml

The following request

[http://www.distance24.org/route.json?stops=Hamburg|Berlin](http://www.distance24.org/route.json?stops=Hamburg%7CBerlin)

opened in a browser, will return a json structure containing the distance between Hamburg and Berlin plus a lot of additional information related to these cities and the route between them.

So I wrote this code just to test it out:

```
import json
import requests
url = 'http://www.distance24.org/route.json?stops=Hamburg|Berlin' 
info = requests.request("GET", url)
info = json.loads(info.text) 
print(info['distance'])
```

and the result of the print was 0, which is definitely not the distance from Hamburg to Berlin.

I'm a bit new to this, so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: It's an API issue not the Python programming. As per API, the result is 0

Comment: @TusharNiras the API is fine. It's how the OP is using `requests`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you should be using `requests`.

Try this:

```python
import requests

endpoint = "https://www.distance24.org/route.json?stops=Hamburg|Berlin"
print(requests.get(endpoint).json()["distance"])
```

Output:

```
256
```

And here's how to get a Hamburg abstract, for example:

```
import requests

endpoint = "https://www.distance24.org/route.json?stops=Hamburg|Berlin"
response = requests.get(endpoint).json()

hamburg_abstract = response["stops"][0]["wikipedia"]["abstract"]
print(hamburg_abstract)
```

Output:

```
Hamburg, officially Free and Hanseatic City of Hamburg, is the second-largest city in Germany, the thirteenth largest German state, and the sixth-largest city in the European Union. The city is home to over 1.8 million people, while the Hamburg Metropolitan Region has more than 4.3 million inhabitants. Situated on the river Elbe, the port of Hamburg is the second largest port in Europe (after the Port of Rotterdam) and 11th-largest worldwide.
```

Comment: thanks! What was wrong with how I used requests? When is using the requests.request() function appropriate?